Why am I having trouble enabling "Secure Boot" / UEFI on Windows 10 to Windows 11?
I want to upgrade my Windows 10 PC to Windows 11, and I am failing at turning on "Secure Boot" / UEFI. My system meets all other requirements.

The Microsoft article "Convert an existing Windows 10 Installation from Legacy BIOS to UEFI" told me to run the Command Prompt "mbr2gpt.exe /disk:1 /validate /allowFullOS", which yielded "Disk layout validation failed for disk 1".

For some reason, "Disk Management" says my "Active" partition is Drive D (disk 0), even though the Windows 10 directory is on C: (Disk 1).

I am afraid of just right-clicking on Disk 1 and selecting "Mark Partition as Active", so I stopped and am asking you for help here.
Any ideas? I'm glad to add any needed info.

Given your Partition layout it will not be possible to enable Secure Boot since you cannot convert your disk to GPT in order to switch to UEFI mode. There is no solution to your problem that doesn’t result in a clean install of Windows. Marking the disk absolutely will NOT solve your problem

What you might try (and I'm not at all sure this is feasible -- comments on this comment would be appreciated): 1. Image the entire drive. 2. Remove all partitions. 3. Install Windows 10 from ISO de novo, letting it partition the drive. 4. Restore the Windows partition to that drive (hopefully, keeping UEFI mode).
